# Can anyone explain to me what the following python code?

Tags: python, list, syntax, word2vec

Can anyone explain to me what the following python code is doing,

```
def sentence_to_vec(sentence_list: List[Sentence], embedding_size: int, a: float=1e-3):
```

I cannot understand, sentence_list: List[Sentence].
From what I understand it forces only lists of Sentences to be passed. Am I right?
And if so how do I typecast a list into the required type?

PS: This code from https://github.com/peter3125/sentence2vec/blob/master/sentence2vec.py

Comment: type hints are really just hints, they are not enforced, you *could* pass anything as parameter, in this case preferrably a list.

Answer (score 0):

They are type hints. Module tells you that it expects first parameter to be list of Sentence objects. Type hints does not enforce anything so you can pass anything but it probably breaks if given object something other than list of Sentences.

List is builtin list object. Sentence is probably defined in module. How you construct these Sentence objects depends on module it is defined in. So you should check that. As long as you give list of Sentence, you are fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the creation of the Sentence objects part? The issue I am getting is that I cannot call a certain function defined within the Sentence class with a Sentence object from the list passed to the above function(sentence2vec).

Comment: @SuheldeepSarkar, I'm not familiar with the code but there is an example at the end of code in the link.